# Is it possible to attach ssh-add / ssh-agent to an existing pid

Tags: ssh, systemd, sshd, ssh-agent

I am trying to set up some clients ready for one server to ssh to each of them.

I have created a service for the `ssh-agent` on server.

From `systemctl --user status ssh-agent.service` I can see a pid:

```
● ssh-agent.service - SSH authentication agent
     Loaded: loaded (/etc/xdg/systemd/user/ssh-agent.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
     Active: active (running) since Mon 2022-08-01 17:31:59 CEST; 9min ago
   Main PID: 2761 (ssh-agent)
     CGroup: /user.slice/user-1000.slice/user@1000.service/ssh-agent.service
             └─2761 /usr/bin/ssh-agent -a /run/user/1000/ssh-agent.socket -D

Aug 01 17:31:59 node0 systemd[880]: Started SSH authentication agent.
Aug 01 17:31:59 node0 ssh-agent[2761]: SSH_AUTH_SOCK=/run/user/1000/ssh-agent.socket; export SSH_AUTH_SOCK;
Aug 01 17:31:59 node0 ssh-agent[2761]: echo Agent pid 2761;
```

Is it possible to `eval "$(ssh-agent)"` using this pid, to be able to `ssh-add` to this instance.

Problem is that I have to manually log out and in again, to be able to add to the right ssh-agent?

Answer (score 0):

The output of `ssh-agent` consists of shell code to set the environment variables `SSH_AUTH_SOCK` and `SSH_AGENT_PID`. Both are in the quoted output. Therefore after running these commands in a `bash` or `/bin/sh` shell, any process started from that shell will use the running agent:

> SSH_AUTH_SOCK=/run/user/1000/ssh-agent.socket; export SSH_AUTH_SOCK
> SSH_AGENT_PID=2761; export SSH_AGENT_PID

Notes:

1. The values of `SSH_AUTH_SOCK` and `SSH_AGENT_PID` have to be taken from the `systemctl` command as they will typically be different each time the service is started.
2. Only processes started from the shell process in which the commands were run will have the exported variables in their environment, therefore only these processes will use the running agent.